# Возможные комбинации элементов в списке

Tags: java, алгоритм, list, arraylist, комбинаторика

Есть список

```java
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
arrayList.add("DHB3618WN2Y19");
arrayList.add("DSB18WN2Y19");
arrayList.add("DHK2518WN2Y19");
arrayList.add("DHD1118WN2Y19");
arrayList.add("DHB18WN2Y19");

System.out.println(String.join(";", arrayList));
```

Нужно создать такое количество строк сколько элементов в списке

И в каждой созданной строке должны быть все элементы через разделитель

Например из

```
12345
```

нужно получить

```
2;3;4;5
3;4;5;1
4;5;1;2
5;1;2;3
1;2;3;4
```

Подскажите алгоритм?

Comment: Для начала напишет зачем это вам? Вы хотите из букв составить все возможные комбинации? Если да, то ваш ответ в виде 5 строчек неправильный, вариантов в 5 раз больше

Comment: Мне нужно для списка товаров заполнить похожие товары (типа перелинковки)
Мой ответ - это один из 5 результатов, который нужно получить
Т.е. я беру группу SKU и создаю связи
Потом это все в Excel уйдет через HashMap, где ключем будет SKU, а значением - его связи (другие SKU)